# Flutter iOS goes into background, timer not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hi I have an iOS app for flutter. I have a timer scheduled to run every 30 seconds to display a push notification. When the app is in foreground it works fine.

When the app goes into background (`AppLifecycleState.paused`), the push notification does not appear anymore every 30 seconds. Does the timer stop running after going into background? Am I doing it wrongly?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{ 
  Timer notiTimer;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    notiTimer.cancel();
  }

  void startTimer(){
    notiTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (timer) {
      showNotification()
    });
  }

  Future<void> showNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Min, priority: Priority.Min, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        'Mobile App',
        'Notification Appear',
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: '');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?